# How I set any distribution for Debian package?

Tags: launchpad, source-packages

When I try to make a Debian source package for Launchpad, in /debian/changelog file, I must set a distribution like this:

```
package-name (1.0-1) trusty; urgency=low
...
```

Now, I want to release my package for any distribution. What I should to do?

Answer (score 0):

That is an issue for the repository that distributes your package, not your package itself. If you want to go with a generic name, pick `stable`.

Comment: stable dose not accepted by Launchpad!

Answer (score 0):

The debian/changelog file format supports multiple distributions, separated by space:

```
package-name (1.0-1) trusty bionic eoan focal; urgency=low
```

for example.

If you build with debuild, lintian will issue the following error:

```
E: libsdrplay-api changes: multiple-distributions-in-changes-file trusty bionic eoan focal
```

but still builds a valid package. The reason is the debian repository doesn't accept multiple distributions for a package: https://lintian.debian.org/tags/multiple-distributions-in-changes-file.html

I don't know if Launchpad accepts it.

Usually it is better to generate a package per distribution but in some cases it can make sense to target several if there is really no distribution specificity and the targeted repository supports it.

Comment: I tried it on Launchpad and it failed with this error message: `Rejected:
Unable to find distroseries: bionic focal`

Answer (score 0):

When building a package in PPA from git sources with a build recipe the problem doesn't occur and published packages are set with the distro that it was built for.